# Second JPanel window too small and third JPanel won't display

Tags: java, swing

I'm using borderlayout with a single JFrame and multiple JPanels. With my second JPanel the window is small and also my third JPanel doesn't display at all, I just get a grey window. Really grateful if someone could show me what is wrong. Below are my four classes. Thanks in advance :)

```
import javax.swing.Box;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;  
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;



public class FrontScreen implements ActionListener
{  
    private static JRadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3;
    private static final JFrame f = new JFrame("Welcome to Ballon d'or , created by Darren Estcourt");
    private static JButton b;
    private static JPanel myFirstPanel; 
    private static JLabel ballondor , trophylabel;
    private static String firstName , surname;

    public FrontScreen()
    {

    }
    public void CreateAndShowFrontScreen()
    {  

        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        myFirstPanel = new JPanel();
        myFirstPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        f.add(myFirstPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ballondor = new JLabel("Ballon d'or");
        ballondor.setToolTipText("Ballon d'or tooltip");
        myFirstPanel.add(ballondor);

        Icon trophy = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Ballondor.jpg"));
        trophylabel = new JLabel("Please choose an option, then click OK" , trophy, SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        trophylabel.setToolTipText("Trophy Label tooltip");
        myFirstPanel.add(trophylabel);


        rb1 = new JRadioButton("Start New Game");  
        rb2 = new JRadioButton("Load Game");
        rb3 = new JRadioButton("Quit");

        Box box1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        box1.add(rb1); // TEST VERTICAL RADIO BUTTONS !
        box1.add(rb2);
        box1.add(rb3);


        myFirstPanel.add(box1);


        ButtonGroup bg=new ButtonGroup();  
        bg.add(rb1);
        bg.add(rb2);
        bg.add(rb3);  

        b = new JButton("OK");
        myFirstPanel.add(b);

        b.addActionListener(this);

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {

                      @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
                      {
                        if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f, "Are you sure ?" , "Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION ) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                            {
                                f.setVisible(false);
                                f.dispose();
                            }
                        else{
                            }
                      }
                  }); 
          }  // OUT OF SCOPE !!!!!!     


          @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {  
                if(rb1.isSelected())
                {
                myFirstPanel.setVisible(false);
                ManagerName panel = new ManagerName();
                f.add(panel);
                f.pack();

                panel.setVisible(true);

                }  
                if(rb2.isSelected())
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f ,"Which saved game would you like to load?", "Load game", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);  
                } 
                if(rb3.isSelected())
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }  

            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException , ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
            {  

                     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
                                   {
                                         public void run() 
                                         {
                                                FrontScreen test = new FrontScreen();
                                                test.CreateAndShowFrontScreen();
                                                f.pack();
                                                f.setVisible(true);

                                         }
                                    });

                                Database passFirstNameObject = new         Database(firstName , surname);
                      passFirstNameObject.setFirstName(firstName);

             } // end main
       }      

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;  
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import java.sql.*;


    /**
     *
     * @author Darren Estcourt
     */

       public class ManagerName extends JPanel implements ActionListener
       {

        private final JLabel firstNameLabel , surnameLabel;
        private final JButton confirmNames , quit;
        private String firstName , surname;


        private final JTextField myTextField , myTextField2;



        public ManagerName()
        {

            setBackground(Color.GREEN);


            firstNameLabel = new JLabel("Please enter your first name");

            add(firstNameLabel);


            myTextField = new JTextField(20); // or use 20 columns
            add(myTextField);
            myTextField.addActionListener(this);

            surnameLabel = new JLabel("Please enter your surname");
            add(surnameLabel);

            myTextField2 = new JTextField(20);
            add(myTextField2);
            myTextField2.addActionListener(this);

            confirmNames = new JButton("Submit Names");
            confirmNames.addActionListener(this);
            add(confirmNames);

            quit = new JButton("Quit");
            quit.addActionListener(this);
            add(quit);

           }



            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {  
                    if(e.getSource()==confirmNames)
                    {

                          firstName = myTextField.getText();
                          surname = myTextField2.getText();
                          try{
                          Database passFirstNameObject = new Database(firstName , surname);
                          passFirstNameObject.setFirstName(firstName);
                          passFirstNameObject.setSurname(surname);
                          Database.databaseMethod(passFirstNameObject);
                          }
                          catch(SQLException i)
                          {
                              System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                          }
                          catch(ClassNotFoundException a)
                          {
                              System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                          }
                          catch(InstantiationException b)
                          {
                              System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                          }
                          catch(IllegalAccessException c)
                          {
                              System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                          }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your name is : " + firstName + " " + surname);
                        this.setVisible(false);
                    NewGame callNewGamePanel = new NewGame();
                    this.add(callNewGamePanel);

                    callNewGamePanel.setVisible(true);
                        }  

                    if(e.getSource()==quit)
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }  

                }    


       }
------------------------------------------------------------------------

    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;  
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import java.awt.Color;


    public class NewGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener
    { 
      private final String[] premierLeagueClubs = {"Arsenal" , "Bournemouth" , "Burnley" , "Chelsea" , "Crystal Palace" , 
      "Everton" , "Hull City" , "Leicester City" , "Liverpool" , "Manchester United" , "Manchester City" , "Middlesborough" , 
      "Southampton" , "Stoke City", "Sunderland", "Swansea City", "Tottenham Hotspur" , "Watford" , "West Brom" , "West Ham"};
      private final JRadioButton[] rb = new JRadioButton[20];

        JButton confirmTeam , quit;
        String teamName;
        JLabel label1; 

        public NewGame()
        {  
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);

            label1 = new JLabel("Please choose a team");
            add(label1);

            for (int i = 0; i < premierLeagueClubs.length; i++) 
            {
                rb[i] = new JRadioButton(premierLeagueClubs[i]);
                rb[i].setActionCommand(premierLeagueClubs[i]);
            }

            confirmTeam = new JButton("OK");
            confirmTeam.addActionListener(this);
            add(confirmTeam);

            for(int j=0; j < 20; j++)
            {
            add(rb[j]);
            }

            ButtonGroup bg=new ButtonGroup();  

            int startvalueBG;
            int endvalueBG=19;
            for(startvalueBG=0; startvalueBG <= endvalueBG; startvalueBG++)
              {
              bg.add(rb[startvalueBG]);
              }



            quit = new JButton("Quit");
            quit.addActionListener(this);
            add(quit);


          }


                @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {  

                    if(e.getSource()==confirmTeam)
                    {
                       for(int i=0; i < 20; i++){
                       if(rb[i].isSelected())
                       {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "You chose:" + premierLeagueClubs[i]);

                       }
                    }
                    if(e.getSource()==quit)
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    } 
                }


    }
    }
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    import java.sql.*;

    public class Database
    {

      private String firstName , surname;

        public Database(String firstName , String surname)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.surname = surname;
        }
        public void setFirstName(String firstName)
                    {
                        this.firstName = firstName;
                    }
                    public String getFirstName()
                    {
                        return firstName;
                    }   
                    public void setSurname(String surname)
                    {
                        this.surname = surname;
                    }
                    public String getSurname()
                    {
                        return surname;
                    }

          public static void databaseMethod(Database passFirstNameObject) throws SQLException , ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,IllegalAccessException 
          {



            String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ballondor?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";

            Connection connOne = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "Lucia290907");
            Connection connTwo = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "Lucia290907");

            Statement st1 = connOne.createStatement();
            Statement st2 = connTwo.createStatement();
                              Class.forName(myDriver).newInstance();



                                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"List of team names" ,TeamName, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);  

                              System.out.println("The first attempt :" + passFirstNameObject.getFirstName() + passFirstNameObject.getSurname());
                                        st2.executeUpdate("insert into managername (firstName,surname) values('"+passFirstNameObject.getFirstName()+"' , '"+passFirstNameObject.getSurname()+"')");   // UPDATING MYSQL DATABASE
                              //         } // end while loop

                                        st1.close();




        }


    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: `f.add(panel);` A panel has already been added to the `CENTER` of the `BorderLayout`. Each position in a border layout can display a maximum of one component.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will try to follow the guidelines for posting code, I just did this in a rush. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second window is small because you call `pack()`, which will resize the window to honor the preferred sizes of its child components :

From `FrontScreen` :

```
        ManagerName panel = new ManagerName();
        f.add(panel);
        f.pack();
```

Your third panel (`NewGame`) never displays because you first make the second panel (`ManagerName`) invisible, then add the third panel to it, so obviously it is also invisible.

Note that calling `setVisible(true)` on a child component if its container is not visible, won't make it suddenly visible .

From `ManagerName` (the second panel) :

```
        this.setVisible(false);
        NewGame callNewGamePanel = new NewGame();
        this.add(callNewGamePanel);
        callNewGamePanel.setVisible(true);
```

Calling

```
this.getParent().add(callNewGamePanel);
```

instead of

```
this.add(callNewGamePanel);
```

would actually add this third panel directly to the window's content .

Also take note of what **Andrew Thompson** said, with its default `BorderLayout`, each time you call `add(Component)` on the window or its content pane, the added component will replace the previous component :

> f.add(panel); A panel has already been added to the CENTER of the
>   BorderLayout. Each position in a border layout can display a maximum
>   of one component.

Comment: Thanks Berger, that's really useful.

Comment: Can anyone provide a link which explains the getParent() method used above, I have googled it, and can only find out that it returns a string such a directory or file name, is that what is happening here? This newb is a bit confused!

Comment: @DarrenEstcourt : It isn't this one, it is the `getParent` method from class `Component`, that returns the `Container` this component belongs to : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent()